# Hide Add button Jquery Datatable Editable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to hide ADD button in Jquery Datatables editable as below but it doesn't work.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
  AddNewRowButtonOptions: { label: "Add...",
                        icons: {primary:'ui-icon-plus'},
                        display: none

        }
```

I tried following options but it still doesnt work

```
  {'#example').dataTable().makeEditable({

            oAddNewRowButtonOptions: "destroy",
            oDeleteRowButtonOptions: {  label: "Remove", 
                            icons: {primary:'ui-icon-trash'}
            },

            oAddNewRowFormOptions: {    
                title: 'title',
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,    
                minWidth: 500,
                minHeight: 450,
                closeOnEscape: false,
                close: function( event, ui ) {
                        resetSuccessOrErrorMessages();
                    }

            },
            sAddDeleteToolbarSelector: ".addDeleteToolbar"

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will convert it to the jquery-ui's button, try use:

```
$('#example').dataTable().makeEditable({
    oAddNewRowButtonOptions: "destroy"
});
```